# Apache Adds Trailing Slash Despite RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a simple *.htaccess* to handle everything with a PHP script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My  *index.php* just  echoes  server  variables at  the  moment (with  a
`print_r($_SERVER)`); Everything works fine, I  type anything in the URL
and  the  *index.php*  contents  are shown.  However,  considering  this
structure:

```
test/           # document root
  folder/       # empty folder
  index.php
  .htaccess
```

I noticed that accessing `[site]/folder`  first redirects the browser to
`[site]/folder/` and then shows the  proper *index.php* contents. Why is
this happening? Isn't  the rewrite rule supposed  to redirect everything
"as is"?

This is being used  with virtual host set up to  test a website locally.
Configured  with the  bare minimum.  Could there  be other  apache files
being loaded prior to my *.htaccess*?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/
</VirtualHost>
```

Using OS X 10.10 currently.

Comment: The problem you're facing has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843293/apache-rewrite-rule-which-works-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash) ?

Comment: @Tolsadus I checked the link but I don't see the answer to this in there. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` doesn't do that, look at the `DirectorySlash` directive as it controls whether Apache does this or not: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: @Unbeliever adding `DirectorySlash Off` solved it. Could you add this as answer? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As determined in the comments above, the `DirectorySlash` directive controls this particular Apache behaviour and the rewriterule did not cause it. This directive defaults to *on*. If you set it to *off*, then when a URI that maps to a directory on the file system is requested without a trailing slash, Apache will not redirect the request to one with a trailing slash.

More information in the documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash